# Response MIME type for Spring Boot actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have updated a Spring Boot application from 1.4.x to 1.5.1 and the Spring Actuator endpoints return a different MIME type now:

For example, `/health` is now `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json` instead simply `application/json`.

How can I change this back?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The endpoints return a content type that honours what the client's request says it can accept. You will get an `application/json` response if the client send an `Accept` header that asks for it:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Ok, that at least works for my own applications and the others that behave good. For Firefox I have to look for some setting, it will always download endpoints instead displaying them. Thanks.

Comment: I was just bitten by this as well. May I ask why it was changed? It's a bit of a PITA to change the settings of all the browsers in use in our company. I haven't even found out yet how to do this in Safari or browers on smart phones. Does the change by any chance has anything to do with the following issue? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7648

Comment: This still changes the content-type received in clients that don't provide application/json.  Why didn't you keep the behaviour for v1 and just change it in v2? 

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7967, "We're going to break things in 2.0 so returning the content type in 1.x would be a good thing to do."  (so lets break thinks in v1 also >:‑) )

Anyway custom health endpoint implemented now.

Comment: "Break things" means changing the structure of the response body. A well-written client should be unaffected by the change made in 1.5.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I will forward that information to the mobile app developers :-) Will instead override the health API like below to keep things smooth.

Comment: @kap The trick with Firefox is that newer versions of the browser have a nice built-it JSON viewer, but don't acknowledge the `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json` as an actual JSON type. You can use the JSONView plugin, with checking two options there: `Include "application/json" in the HTTP Accept header for requests` and `Use built-in Firefox JSON viewer`. This will make the browser to ask for `application/json` type in response, but JSONView won't interfere with reading the response, it will be read by Firefox as a normal JSON.

Comment: For firefox Quantum users you may display the json properly using this extension : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/json-content-type-override/

Answer (score 14):

In response to the comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/2952093/kap (my reputation is to low to create a comment): when using Firefox to check endpoints that return JSON I use the Add-on JSONView. In the settings there is an option to specify alternate JSON content types, just add `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json`and you'll see the returned JSON in pretty print inside your browser.

Answer (score 6):

Since SpringBoot 2.0.x the suggested solution in implementing the `EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer` doesn't work any longer.

The good news is, the solution is simpler now.

The Bean `EndpointMediaTypes` needs to be provided. It is provided by the SpringBoot class `WebEndpointAutoConfiguration` by default.

Providing your own could look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorEndpointConfig {

    private static final List<String> MEDIA_TYPES = Arrays
        .asList("application/json", ActuatorMediaType.V2_JSON);

    @Bean
    public EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes() {
        return new EndpointMediaTypes(MEDIA_TYPES, MEDIA_TYPES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As you noticed the content type for actuators have changed in 1.5.x.

If you in put "application/json" in the "Accept:" header you should get the usual content-type.

But if you don't have any way of modifying the clients, this snippet returns health (without details) and original content-type (the 1.4.x way).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/health", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class HealthController {

    @Inject
    HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Health > health() throws IOException {
        Health health = healthEndpoint.health();
        Health nonSensitiveHealthResult = Health.status(health.getStatus()).build();
        if (health.getStatus().equals(Status.UP)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(nonSensitiveHealthResult);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(nonSensitiveHealthResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration (move away existing health)

```
endpoints.health.path: internal/health
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the code in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2449 (which also works fine but completely removes the new type) I came up with

```
@Component
public class ActuatorCustomizer implements EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer {

    static class Fix extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {
            Object attribute = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (attribute instanceof LinkedHashSet) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                LinkedHashSet<MediaType> lhs = (LinkedHashSet<MediaType>) attribute;
                if (lhs.remove(ActuatorMediaTypes.APPLICATION_ACTUATOR_V1_JSON)) {
                    lhs.add(ActuatorMediaTypes.APPLICATION_ACTUATOR_V1_JSON);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void customize(EndpointHandlerMapping mapping) {
        mapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] {new Fix()});
    }
}
```

which puts the new vendor-mediatype last so that it will use `application/json` for *all* actuator endpoints when nothing is specified.

Tested with spring-boot 1.5.3

Comment: Quick question: `if (...was removed...) { ...re-add...}`? `HashSet.remove()` [removes only if the element was present](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove-java.lang.Object-). This works, but why? :-)

Comment: Your code switches `[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json, application/json]` to `[application/json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json]`. What works as well (and might be less confusing): `lhs.remove(ActuatorMediaTypes.APPLICATION_ACTUATOR_V1_JSON); lhs.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);`

Comment: @crusy I don't know what that special new type is used / intended for so I don't want to remove it. It can stay in the list of supported mediatypes so code that wants it can still request it, but it should come after `application/json` for me because I want to use a default browser to get json. Since a `LinkedHashSet` keeps insertion oder, I simply remove it and re-add it to sort it to the back. With an `if` to make sure I don't modify stuff that didn't have this new type in the first place.

Comment: Works for me in Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and Grails 3.3.0.RC1, but only if I change the customize method to instead contain

        `mapping.setInterceptors(new Fix())`

Answer (score 2):

To support `application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json` in Firefox's built in JSON viewer, you can install this addon: [json-content-type-override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/json-content-type-override/). It will convert content types that contain "json" to "application/json".

**Update:** Firefox 58+ has built-in support for these mime types, and no addon is needed anymore. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1388335

Comment: It's says it won't be necessary for Firefox 58+: "The purpose of this addon has been natively integrated into Firefox 58."

Comment: How do we turn on the override in Firefox 58+? I'm on 62 and firefox still requests to save the file rather than just displaying it